# Security: Creating Unique User Connections with Client-Side Only Code?

Tags: javascript, performance, security, database-design, client-side

Lets say **I need to share a resource between 2 users under these conditions**:

1. **All saving to the database is client-side**
2. **There are no unique usernames**

An example would be adding a person to your contact list and sharing a private thread(A private threadID) between you two.

Eventually there are many connections and many threadIDs. **How do you manage this is in a secure and efficient way?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, once you are trusting the client, you are trusting the client.  Security-wise that limits you in some pretty profound ways.  The server never really knows what is going on at the client's side of the connection and so it cannot enforce any real security in this regard server-side.

THe closest thing you can do is send data encrypted for a user but I suspect that has overhead you don't want to incur.

Otherwise you just have to assume people are not going to try to bypass your security.  If they do, all bets are off.  But then that means you don't have to worry about it either.....

Your other option is to enforce this is some sort of middleware which does handle authorization tokens.